# Windows 10 alternative authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, winapi, credential-providers

Let's say I want to implement alternative (not local and not AD) identity and authentication for Windows 10. So that my system allows to

- List/search available users and groups through regular API/GUI
- Log in with custom credentials (like username and SMS code). So that I probably return user SID and group SIDs, but ACLs work as usual.

What windows systems should I extend?

Comment: Have you read Microsoft's documentation on [Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/authentication-portal) yet? It covers the various auth technologies that Windows supports and how to implement custom authentication

Comment: Yes, but I was confused by this documentation.

Answer (score 1):

A Credential Provider basically allows you to display stuff and then logon if you supply the correct credentials. What you do in between doesn't matter.

You could have your usual credentials in database and implement your authenticaton method.

1. Make the credential provider generate an SMS code associated to the corresponding user in **custom database** (Retrieving the expected user based on [Enter criteria here]).
2. Send it.
3. Wait for the user entering the above-mentionned code and pressing 'submit'.
4. If entered code is correct, deserialize the normal credentials to start the connection.

Comment: I don't have normal credentials, if you mean username and password.

Comment: I mean those you're passing to WinLogon for the authentication. How are you logging in usually ?